# Creating PDF through Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, pdf

I want to create a PDF file with excel data. I have rows of data in excel, for each row I want to create a PDF file and save it to my machine. How to do it with excel or access macro in vba?

Answer (score 0):

You may use File / Export / Create PDF/XPS Document menu for this purpose.

When this feature is used when recording a VBA macro, below code is generated, you may use it or get your own code by recording a macro. Then you may use the code within a loop to create multiple PDFs with one go.

This feature creates the PDF using the printable area of your sheet. So you may have to adjust the print area from your code before each PDF creation.

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "\\test.pdf", Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.

```
Sub Save_Each_Row_As_PDF()

myrange = "A1:J10"
lastRow = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For myRow = 2 To lastRow

    Range("A" & myRow & ":J" & myRow).Select
    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\your_path_here\Book" & myRow & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        False
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is myrange variable used?